# Different results IN and NOT IN in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to do two query, in my mind it should give me the same result but no

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_id as id
    FROM users_roles as ur
    WHERE 
        ur.role_id = 10
        OR ur.role_id = 12
    )
```

i have the result:

```
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

and second change first `NOT IN` to `IN` and wrap it to outer `NOT IN` is

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT users.id
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id IN (
        SELECT user_id as id
        FROM users_roles as ur
        WHERE 
            ur.role_id = 10
            OR ur.role_id = 12
        )
)
```

with result

```
  count  
---------
 3150136
(1 row)
```

what is wrong with first query?

more details for second query:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM users
WHERE users.id IN (
    SELECT user_id as id
    FROM users_roles as ur
    WHERE 
        ur.role_id = 10
        OR ur.role_id = 12
    )

 count 
-------
 40320
(1 row)
```

and

```
select count(1) from users;
  count  
---------
 3190466
```

edit by user query:

```
database=# \d users_roles
                          Table "public.users_roles"
  Column  |  Type   |                        Modifiers                         
----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------
 user_id  | integer | 
 role_id  | integer | 
 track_id | integer | 
 id       | integer | not null default nextval('users_roles_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "users_roles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "uniq_users_roles" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_id, role_id)
    "uq_users_roles_role_track" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (role_id, track_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_roles_track_id" FOREIGN KEY (track_id) REFERENCES tracks(id)
    "fk_users_roles_roles" FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(id)
    "fk_users_roles_users" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

and select

```
SELECT Count(user_id) as totalusers FROM users_roles as ur WHERE ur.role_id = 10 OR ur.role_id = 12;
     totalusers 
------------
      40320
```

P.S.

```
database=# select version();
                                                   version                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, 64-bit
```

Comment: In your second query, you are basically saying "WHERE id NOT IN (Empty result)", which -from my understanding- would result in everything being returned.

Comment: Any null values in users_roles?

Comment: @waka thank you i added details looks like not empty but maybe i'm wrong again

Comment: Instead of using count(1) use the primary key column like count(id)

Comment: @Mittal it gives the same results, not for the case, of course i tried it

Comment: What is result of this query:  SELECT Count(user_id) as totalusers
    FROM users_roles as ur
    WHERE 
        ur.role_id = 10
        OR ur.role_id = 12

Comment: @jarlh edit add users_roles description

Comment: @Mittal edit add result

Comment: @jarlh now i understand what you mean, thank you, it was very strange situation for me

Comment: Also you should ask yourself : what does it *mean*, a record in `users_roles` with user_id=NULL? "sombody has a role and a track, but I don't know who (s)he is"? (the same for the other FKs)

Comment: @joop thank you, already, this is legacy code with strange solution, merge two tables in one, `users_roles` and `tracks_roles` why? no one know it)

Comment: With three key elements, there could be a possible 4NF problem. Except for the NULLs, this *legacy* could be the correct model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be because the table `user_roles` might have NULL `user_id` when `role_id` = `10` or `role_id` = `12`.

First query becomes something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN (id1, id2, id3, NULL, id4, NULL, id5,...)
```

Here a given `users.id` will be compared with all values in the list and only if it is not equal to any id value in the above list, it will qualify to show up in the output.

With NULL values present in the list, the `NOT IN` evaluates the condition for a given `users.id` as [`users.id`<>`id1` AND `users.id`<>`id2` AND... `users.id`<>`NULL` AND `users.id`<>`id5`] which you would expect is TRUE but SQL treats it as FALSE because it evaluates `users.id`<>`NULL` as FALSE, hence evaluating the whole expression as FALSE and excludes that `users.id` from the result. This happens all other `users.id` in the `users` table which is why you got 0 entries in the output.

FYI: `id` = `NULL` => UNKNOWN as well as `id` <> `NULL` => UNKNOWN where UNKNOWN is neither TRUE nor FALSE(but in the context of your problem you can still say `not TRUE` when you were expecting it to be `TRUE`)  because `NULL` is actually an "unknown" with no value at all.

To avoid this, you can remove NULLs from the inner list as given below:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN (
SELECT user_id as id
FROM users_roles as ur
WHERE 
    (ur.role_id = 10 OR ur.role_id = 12) AND ur.user_id IS NOT NULL
)
```

This was with `NOT IN`.

However, you won't face this problem when you use `IN` because if there is a non-NULL `users.id` which is a match in the list, then it will be included in the output which is why you got 40,320 records in the other query.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Those evaluations return `UNKNOWN`, the third logic value in SQL's logic, not `FALSE`. Easily demonstrated by wrapping those expressions in `NOT()` and observing that they don't become `TRUE`. E.g. `NOT(NULL = NULL)` is not `TRUE`.

Comment: My point was that *all* of those locations where you assert that a result is `FALSE` are incorrect. Not just the `NULL = NULL` one.

Comment: Right. Made the changes. Thanks.